# Make product name to be unique

Tags: python, openerp-7

I have a question
when I try to override product.product to make it name to be unique
i add to it

```
import logging
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
import time
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp
from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT
from openerp.tools.translate import _
from openerp import netsvc
from datetime import datetime, date

    class product_override(osv.osv):
        _name = 'product.product'
        _inherit = 'product.product'
        _columns = {

                    'min_charge' : fields.float(_('Min.Charge')),
                    }

        _sql_constraints = [ ('name_uniq_1', 'unique(name)', _('Name for Product must be unique!')), ]
```

but it doesn't work. Any help? Am I missing some thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**product.product** is inherited from **product.template** by delegation. **name** field is present in **product.template**, not in **product.product**

If you look at the log you will get 
`openerp.sql_db: Programming error: column "name" named in key does not exist, in query ALTER TABLE "product_product" ADD CONSTRAINT "product_product_name_uniq_1" unique(name)`

Change your code to

```
import logging
from openerp.osv import fields, osv
import time
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp
from openerp.tools import DEFAULT_SERVER_DATE_FORMAT
from openerp.tools.translate import _
from openerp import netsvc
from datetime import datetime, date

class product_template_override(osv.osv):
    _name = 'product.template'
    _inherit = 'product.template'
    _sql_constraints = [ ('name_uniq_1', 'unique(name)', _('Name for Product must be unique!')) ]

class product_override(osv.osv):
        _name = 'product.product'
        _inherit = 'product.product'
        _columns = {

                    'min_charge' : fields.float(_('Min.Charge')),
                    }
```